# CSS calculate max-width using vw and left position

Tags: css, responsive, calc

Is there a way to calculate max-width in CSS using the viewport width and the left position of the element? I have a div that contains a dynamic table, which can grow depending on the columns of the uploaded spreadsheet. I want to be able to apply max-width and horizontal scroll for the container, which I can easily do with `100vw`. However, I also have a sidebar that users can toggle. So I'm thinking the best way to compute for max-width is through `100vw - [left position of container div]` or maybe anyone can suggest a better solution for this using purely CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After googling, it seems like this is not supported.

I have fixed my problem, however, by using the class appended to the body when the sidebar is toggled. And considering that the sidebar itself has a fixed width, I did something like this:

```
body{
    div.horizontal-scroll {
        max-width: calc(100vw - 310px);
    }
    &.sidebar-hidden {
        div.horizontal-scroll {
            max-width: calc(100vw - 80px);
        }
    }
}
```